# $\sigma _{0}(n)=\sigma _{0}(n+1)$ will occur infinitely often.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

In 1984, Roger Heath-Brown proved that will occur $\sigma _{0}(n)=\sigma _{0}(n+1)$ infinitely often. How did he prove that? I couldn't find the paper on the internet.

Comment: Heath-Brown, D. R. ["The Divisor Function at Consecutive Integers."](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6990892) Mathematika 31, 141-149, 1984.

Answer (score 2):

The paper is probably

> [The divisor function at consecutive integers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300010743), *Mathematika*, 31 (1984), 141–149

This is not freely available, unfortunately.

See also this paper by Hildebrand which extends Heath-Brown's and is freely available:

> [The divisor function at consecutive integers](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1987.129.307), *Pacific Journal of Mathematics*,   129 (1987) 307–319